# Как сформировать метод с помощью Spring Data по составному полю

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

Есть таблица поля:

**id,
value,
user_id**

Класс-сущность под данную таблицу

в случае использования

```js
 @Query(value = "delete from tokens where user_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteTokenByUserId (Long value);
```

получаю ошибку

> ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tokens")
public class Token {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String value;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public Token() {
    }

    public Token(Long id, String value, User user) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
        this.user = user;
    }
    .....

    }
```

Вот такой интерфейс

```
public interface TokensRepository extends JpaRepository<Token, Long> {

    Optional<Token> findOneByValue(String value);


}
```

Нужно составить метод, который бы удалял бы по составному полю
**user_id** все записи.

Это поле - вторичный ключ по отношению к полю `id` таблицы `users`для которой есть свой класс-сущности **User** 
Я предположил, что прежде чем пользователь получить очередной токен, то перед этим нужно почистить таблицу от старых

```js
@Component
@Transactional
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService {

    private TokensRepository tokensRepository;

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private TokenMapper tokenMapper;


    @Autowired
    public LoginServiceImpl(TokensRepository tokensRepository,
                            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                            UserRepository userRepository,
                            TokenMapper tokenMapper) {
        this.tokensRepository = tokensRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.tokenMapper = tokenMapper;
    }

    /** The method checks of data that user have entered into
     *  form during authentication. If data exists than to equals
     *  these data with data that is into database. If data equals
     *  that generated token.
     *
     *
     * @param userCredentials -It is data that user have entered into
     *                        form during authentication.
     * @return token
     */
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public TokenDto login(UserCredentials userCredentials) throws ResourceNotFoundException {

        String login = userCredentials.getLogin();
        User userByLogin = userRepository.findByLogin(login);

        if(userByLogin != null){

            String passwordFromBase = userByLogin.getPassword();
            String passwordFromForm = userCredentials.getPassword();

            boolean isMatches = passwordEncoder.matches(passwordFromForm, passwordFromBase);


            if(isMatches){

                Long id = userByLogin.getId();

                tokensRepository.deleteTokenByUserId(id);

                String random = RandomStringUtils.random(10, true, true);

                Token token = new Token.Builder()
                        .setUser(userByLogin)
                        .setValue(random)
                        .build();

                tokensRepository.save(token);

                return tokenMapper.tokenToTokenDto(token);

            } else {
                throw new AuthorizationFailedException("The password is not correct!");
            }

        } else {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the specified login exists in the database
     * @param login
     * @return - http status
     * @throws ResourceNotFoundException - if such login not exists that will throw Exception
     */
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getUserByLoginForCredentials(String login)
            throws ResourceNotFoundException {

        User userByLogin = userRepository.findByLogin(login);

        if(userByLogin == null){
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("There is no such user with this login.");
        }

       return ResponseEntity.ok().body(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Но вот в этом месте ошибка

```js
 if(isMatches){

                Long id = userByLogin.getId();

                tokensRepository.deleteTokenByUserId(id);
                
                .....
```

чтобы все-таки запрос отработал, нужно изменить имя метода, чтобы оно не совпадало с правилами по соглашению имен (иначе сначала spring попытается сам составить запрос)
 и кроме того нужно добавить аннотацию  **@Modifying**

```js
 @Modifying
    @Query(value = "delete from tokens where user_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    void deleteTokenUserId(Long value);
```

Но вот использовать удаление там где я получаю **token** - это неверное решение.